# having trouble with foreign key queries

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to execute queries with foreign keys on MySQL Workbench.

In my example, I have three tables: `people`, `places`, and `people_places`.

- In `people`, the primary key is `people_id` and there's a column called `name` with someone's name.
- In `places`, the primary key is `places_id` and there's a column called `placename` with the name of a place.
- `People_places` is a junction table with three columns: `idpeople_places` (primary key), `people_id` (foreign key), and `places_id` (foreign key).  So this table relates a person to a place using their numerical IDs from the other two tables.

Say I want the names of everyone associated with place #3.  So the people_places table has those associations by number, and the people table relates those numbers back to the actual names I want.

How would I execute that query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this to find all the people names who are associated with place id 3.

```
SELECT p.name
FROM people as p
INNER JOIN people_places as pp on pp.people_id = p.people_id
WHERE pp.places_id = 3
```

Comment: +1. The "standard approach" these days would be an inner join. One comment though... the OP is obviously trying to learn. In those circumstances I still feel it's best to provide "not quite the right answer"... Ergo: leave 'em an opportunity to contribute to there success, even if it's a relatively small contribution. Let 'em get some of there OWN runs on the board.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you need to "stitch" all three tables together, yeah?

Something like this:

```
select people.name
from   people        -- 1. I like to start with the table(s) that I want data from, and
     , people_places -- 2. then the "joining" table(s), and
     , places        -- 3. finally the table(s) used "just" for filtering.
where  people.people_id = people_places.people_id  -- join table 1 to table 2
and    people_places.place_id = places.place_id    -- join table 2 to table 3
and    places.name = "BERMUDA"                     -- restrict rows in table 3
```

I'm sure you can do the rest.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I've got it now.